# how to organize code to close file effectively in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read something from a file in Java and then close it. But I don't know where to put the close method.

```
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"));
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            set.add(line);
        }
        //scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("data is not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        //scanner.close();
    }
```

As you can see in the code, there are two places I could possibly put the close method, one is inside try, one is inside finally. 
If I put it in the try clause, it something fails after that, the scanner cannot be closed; however, if I put it in the finally clause, I need to declare the scanner before try-clause, in this way, if the file open fails, the close method in finally does not make sense, because scanner is still null.

I know there must be something wrong in these thoughts, could someone point out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Java 8 I'd highly recommend using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        set.add(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("data is not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

With this pattern java implicitly adds a `finally` block to call `scanner.close()`.

If you can't take advantage of the features of Java 8 then your best option is to declare `scanner` before the `try` block and check for null when closing it in the `finally`:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        set.add(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("data is not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am java6 developer ,it seems great that in java 8 "java implicitly adds a finally block to call scanner.close()". thanx.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```java
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        set.add(line);
    }
    //scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("data is not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    if(scanner != null)
         scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use try-with-resources for this is to open the file separately from the scanner:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(...);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis))
{
    // ...
}
catch ...
```

Then both streams will be closed if they exist.

Comment: The `close()` method of `Scanner` closes the stream it was created with, so calling `scanner.close()` is sufficient to close both the `Scanner` and the stream it's reading from.

Comment: @1337joe If and only if it's executed. If there's an exception constructing the `Scanner`, it wont exist, so it can't be closed, because there is nothing to close, so the expression `new Scanner(new FileInputStream(...))` will leak the `FileInputStream` resource.

Answer (score 0):

The normal idiom (I'm surprised no one has shown it yet) is to declare the variable before the try with no initialization, then set it inside the try. To get what you want, you'd say...

```
Scanner scanner;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"));
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        set.add(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("data is not found");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    scanner.close();
}
```

However, this is not the right way to go. It's best if the try/catch should include only the code that can generate the not found exception. That's the file open. If you need (not done below), refactor the try/catch into its own private method.

```
FileInputStream fis;
try {
  fis = new FileInputStream("data")
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("data is not found");
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;  // Or you can throw another exception here...
}
// Properly used scanners don't raise exceptions, so
// putting this in a try catch block is poor practice.
// (IOExceptions of the stream are caught by the scanner
// and treated as end-of-input.)
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
while (scanner.hasNextLine() {
  String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
  set.add(line);
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: @1a1a11a You don't close the file. scanner.close() does it for you.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this method which follows the iterator pattern of while(hasNext()) -> read -> close.

```
    try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("data"));
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
                set.add(line);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("data is not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
        }
```

This way, the scanner is only not null if the file was opened successfully, and then it is closed after the objects were read. There should not be an exception there, and if you think there might be, you can add in a nested try block to catch a reading exception. Then close the scanner in the first try block.

Comment: In the case that your first example works (the file is found) you're instantiating two `Scanner`s and only calling close on the one attached to the `FileInputStream`, which means you'd be leaking the resource of the `Scanner` attached to `System.in`.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I'll remove the first one. Good catch!